# What error messaging do i add to my windows forms C# program?

Tags: c#, winforms, error-messaging

My program is a prime numbers C# program and I need error messaging that shows what happens when I add letters and/or larger numbers first in the textboxes.
Here is my code:

```
namespace Task_2_Prime_Numbers
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btcalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Find all Prime numbers between the first and last prime numbers
            int firstnum = Convert.ToInt32(number1.Text);
            int lastnum = Convert.ToInt32(number2.Text);

            IbPrime.Items.Clear();

            // See which numbers are factors and add them to the list box
            for (int i = firstnum; i <= lastnum; i++)
            {
                if (IsPrime(i))
                {
                    IbPrime.Items.Add(i);
                }

            }
        }
        private bool IsPrime(int num)
        {
            if (num < 2)
                return false;
            // Looks for a number that evenly divides the sum
            for (int i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++)
                if (num % i == 0)
                    return false;

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `Convert.ToInt32` to [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) and use the result from `int.TryParse` (it's bool)

Comment: I have tried that and it comes up with errors. Does that mean i have to recreate a windows form. I am new to C#.

Answer (score 1):

Use `int.TryParse`.

```
int firstnum, lastnum;
if (!int.TryParse(number1.Text, out firstnum)){
    // Error
}
if (!int.TryParse(number2.Text, out lastnum)){
    // Error
}
if (firstnum >= lastnum){
    // Error
}
```